# moving light with a fading pulse, very bizarre

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, positional-astronomy

October 9th southeast of Denver about 6 miles, looking northwest in the sky approximately 10 inches to the left of Alkaid, a bright light, what at first glance might have been a star, began moving upward about 10 inches with the naked eye. As it moved, it faded out. Then it would appear in the original location and repeat.

This went on for about 5 minutes and then stopped.

I captured video that I intended on a bit of video forensics but I would like to see if anyone can offer up an explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: "10 inches movement" is strange measure for an object at undefined distance in the sky. I suggest to replace that by describing a movement in relation to finger widths or hand widths at the stretched arm (Thumb ~ 2°, hand ~10°).

Comment: How to approximate angular distances by hand: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter#Estimating_angular_diameter_using_the_hand Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob%27s_staff

Comment: 10 inches is the wrong term here as what is 10 inches in the sky? Your 10 inch sky could easily change if you hold the ruler further out. This is why we usually use arcseconds, arc minutes and degrees.

Comment: Almost certainly a Starlink train.  Check https://heavens-above.com/ to verify.